# vim: how to call a script from a line mode?

Tags: vim

A simple question.
I want to make some vim commands but only for selected lines
using shift+v.
Manually is possible: I press `shift+v` and I select the lines I want to modify, then I press `:` and
in the <> interval i put my commands(s, norm, etc).
But if I want to call a script?
I try this: I press `shift+v` and I select the lines I want to modify, then i press `:` and
in the <> interval i put this

```
source scripts/myscript.vim
```

but return error E481.
How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found with a workaround.
Instead of using `shift+v` I put the range of lines which I want to modify directly in the script

```
#!/usr/bin/vim
11,18 s#\\set#exec :#
11,18 norm wwwi:=
```